# Meaning and nuance of 作戦

Tags: meaning, nuances, grammar

I have found a sentence with 作戦 (tactics; strategy; (2) {mil} military operation;)

> ここはウィットなジョークでも飛ばして、堀北の内部ポイントを貯める**作戦**に出よう。
>
> Now I could finally score some points with Horikita by telling some
>   witty jokes.

I understand globally, of course if refers to psychological tactics but still I do not understand the grammar specially the association with に出よう

Could someone explain this to me ?

Comment: Where did "could finally" come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 出る is the third entry under #4 [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B/).

> ある態度をとる。**ある態度で相手に対する。**

To take/adopt a (given) attitude/behavior/manner of acting.
**To face the person you're interacting with with a (given) attitude/behavior/manner of acting.**

In this case, the behavior that is being adopted is the entire sentence between ここは and に出よう. A 作戦, or strategy, typically comprises a plan involving the manner in which one should act going forward, which is why it can be used with に出る.